# Am I being picked up by a proxy sending my IP/request URLs to China? Sketchy

Tags: security, proxy, sniffing

I spun up a new machine on Digital Ocean today which is pre-configured with a web environment. I made an initial request to the new site and found the following *(IP address redacted)* in my nginx access logs:

```
218.65.131.13 - - [16/Apr/2015:07:14:50 -0400] "GET http://218.65.131.13/intoIp.aspx?ip=111.111.111.111:8080 HTTP/1.1" 502 568 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 2.0.50727)"
218.65.131.20 - - [16/Apr/2015:07:42:59 -0400] "GET http://218.65.131.13/intoIp.aspx?ip=111.111.111.111:8080 HTTP/1.1" 502 568 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 2.0.50727)"
218.65.131.13 - - [16/Apr/2015:08:04:08 -0400] "GET http://218.65.131.13/intoIp.aspx?ip=111.111.111.111:8080 HTTP/1.1" 502 568 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 2.0.50727)"
218.65.131.20 - - [16/Apr/2015:08:36:15 -0400] "GET http://218.65.131.13/intoIp.aspx?ip=111.111.111.111:8080 HTTP/1.1" 502 568 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 2.0.50727)"
```

It's obvious that they somehow managed to sniff the request and look to have subsequently passed the request URL to the server `218.65.131.13` because the log also includes the non-standard port number I had used. I did a reverse IP lookup and found this IP to be owned by China Telecom, [as shown here](http://218.65.131.13.ipaddress.com/).

This is a bit troubling since I made the request from a hosted DigitalOcean server to another brand new DigitalOcean server.

I did a traceroute after the fact which didn't turn up anything interesting:

```
traceroute to 111.111.111.111 (111.111.111.111), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  162.243.160.253 (162.243.160.253)  0.459 ms  0.440 ms  0.417 ms
 2  198.211.111.70 (198.211.111.70)  0.407 ms  0.398 ms 198.211.111.66 (198.211.111.66)  0.797 ms
 3  xe-0-3-0-28.r05.nycmny01.us.bb.gin.ntt.net (204.2.241.49)  1.029 ms nyk-b2-link.telia.net (62.115.45.1)  0.705 ms  0.702 ms
 4  xe-0-1-0-34.r05.nycmny01.us.ce.gin.ntt.net (129.250.204.110)  1.631 ms nyk-bb2-link.telia.net (213.155.130.31)  0.752 ms xe-0-1-0-34.r05.nycmny01.us.ce.gin.ntt.net (129.250.204.110)  1.620 ms
 5  nyk-b3-link.telia.net (80.91.247.21)  1.234 ms 162.243.188.230 (162.243.188.230)  1.602 ms 162.243.188.242 (162.243.188.242)  1.869 ms
 6  digitalocean-ic-306497-nyk-b3.c.telia.net (62.115.45.6)  1.863 ms digitalocean-ic-306498-nyk-b3.c.telia.net (62.115.45.10)  1.588 ms example.com (111.111.111.111)  1.576 ms
```

**Any suggestions on what I should be looking for in regards to tracking down how this request was leaked/shared or if there's a security breach somewhere?**

Comment: If you're concerned with your IP being in the body, you might want to also remove your domain name from the traceroute output, also there is a nice [meta post](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/963/what-information-should-i-include-or-obfuscate-in-my-posts/6063#6063). About what to obfuscate and how.

Comment: @Reaces the domain is a replacement as well but I'll use the standard example.com just so people know.

Comment: Wait, where did I get ruby-mynew************.co from then? I can't see it in the edit history. However the domain pings back to DigitalOcean. I must be going blind.